# Data not iterating in select field

Tags: jquery

I am sending ajax when `select` is changed.

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#city").change(function()
                {
                    var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].value;
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '../scripts/get_areas.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {'city_id':id},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            var $area = $('#area');
                            $area.empty();
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {
                                $area.append('<option value=' + data[i].area_id + '>' + data[i].area + '</option>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

This is How I am sending the data and it is returning data as

```
[{"area_id":1,"area":"ABC","area_postal":12345,"city_id":1}]
```

But it is not appending on `select` which has `id="area"`

What is wrong here? It is showing `undefined` on `<select id="area"></select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please convert the data response in to json object . using "jQuery.parseJSON(data)", inside to your for{} . Then append that to `<option>`

Comment: success: function(data)
{
var $area = $('#area');
$area.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"area_id":1,"area":"ABC","area_postal":12345,"city_id":1}' );
$area.append('<option value=' + obj[i].area_id + '>' + obj[i].area + '</option>');
}
}

Comment: It shows data but also in console it is saying  ` obj[i] is undefined`

Comment: I am surprised.. it should work.. any way can you check with this one .. 
--------------------------------
success: function(data)
{
var $area = $('#area');
$area.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
var obj = JSON.parse( '[{"area_id":1,"area":"ABC","area_postal":12345,"city_id":1}]' );

$area.append('<option value=' + obj[i].area_id + '>' + obj[i].area + '</option>');

}
}